# Sort elements img alphabetically by alt in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few elements on side:

https://jsfiddle.net/vvbpvt0c/

```
<figure class="img-space">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150/30ac17" alt="qwqwqwaccusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt">
<figcaption class="text-img">accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt</figcaption></figure>
```

and I want to sort them by img[alt] and show on side, sort() don't work.

Comment: Post your JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a possible way. The sort is done, and they're sorting by figcaption. If you want to do it by the alt text, then you might want to make sure they all have an alt and simply use $(a).find("img").attr("alt") instead of the selector I used. Credit where credit is due, I used http://james.padolsey.com/snippets/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ as a jumping-off point.

```js
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function() {

  var sort = [].sort;

  return function(comparator, getSortable) {

    getSortable = getSortable || function() {
      return this;
    };

    var placements = this.map(function() {

      var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
        parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

        // Since the element itself will change position, we have
        // to have some way of storing its original position in
        // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
        nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
          document.createTextNode(''),
          sortElement.nextSibling
        );

      return function() {

        if (parentNode === this) {
          throw new Error(
            "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
          );
        }

        // Insert before flag:
        parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
        // Remove flag:
        parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

      };

    });

    return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i) {
      placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
    });

  };

})();

$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("figure").sortElements(function(a, b) {
    var aStr = $(a).find("figcaption").text().toUpperCase(),
      bStr = $(b).find("figcaption").text().toUpperCase();
    return aStr.localeCompare(bStr);
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
figcaption {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
figure {
  clear: both;
  height: 175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sort">
  Sort them!
</button>
<figure class="img-space">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/30ac17" alt="accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt">
  <figcaption class="text-img">accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="img-space">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/30ac17" alt="accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt">
  <figcaption class="text-img">aaassaccudsasamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="img-space">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150/30ac17" alt="accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt">
  <figcaption class="text-img">fdsffsfsaccusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt</figcaption>
</figure>
```